# How to connect to the ILO HP Dl380p gen8

Tags: ilo

Followed the below steps as per https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00039812en_us&docLocale=en_US#N1006B

So I do not have a display to the server and trying to use my windows laptop as display. As per the above link the default IP is 192.168.0.120

Connected the ethernet cable to the iLO ethernet port at the back of the server and the other end to my laptop. configured a static IP 192.168.0.86 with subnet mask 255.255.0.0

http://192.168.0.120/ --> Page not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you listed in your post are for a different generation hardware and a packaged product. Simplivity is a solution that use HPE hardware, but those instructions do not apply to what you're doing.

The DL380p Gen8 will show the ILO IP address and information when the system goes through the POST process.

Please connect a VGA monitor and keyboard to configure your ILO via the BIOS settings.

Alternatively, the ILO is set to receive a DHCP IP address by default, so you can connect to an existing network. The Login and Password are located on the server asset tag.